# ¿como cambiar el valor de una variable que se encuentra fuera de todas las funcione en javascript?

Tags: javascript

**hola alguien me puede ayuda tengo una duda como es que puedo cambiar el valor de una variable que se encuentra afuera de todas las funciones pero solo en una funcion quiero llamarla para cambiarle el valor
esto es un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer

```
var numero =1;
function cambiar(){
    numero= 2
}

function llamar(){
  numero= ...; //Aquí *
}
```

`*` aquí es donde quiero que al llamar nuevamente a la variable tenga ya el valor de la anterior función.

Comment: Declarala fuera de las funciones... para que la variable sea global.

Comment: apoyando la idea de @Cig, es eso o la va pasando por parametro y reasignando

Comment: Así como tienes tu ejemplo te va a funcionar, el hecho es que en Javascript las variables tienden a cambiar de valor según se llamen y se les asigne el valor. Es decir, cuando declaras `var numero = 1` en ese instante tiene asignado ese valor, en la función cambiar a la variable `numero` le reasignas un nuevo valor que en este caso es 2 (Por así decirlo) cuando vuelvas a llamar esta variable, va a tener actualizado su valor, en este caso en la función `llamar`

Comment: Las anteriores respuestas son correctas. También puedes llamar a la función llamar() desde cambiar() pasándole el número como argumento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El codigo como lo tienes escrito funciona correctamente, ya que declaraste la variable fuera de las funciones, por lo que es una variable Global.

```js
var numero =1;

cambiar();
llamar();//devuelve 2

function cambiar(){
  numero = 2;
}

function llamar(){
  console.log(numero);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dado que `numero` es una variable **global**:

- puedes simplemente invocar a la función `cambiar` desde donde y cuando quieras que su valor cambie
- puedes usar la variable desde cualquier ámbito por el mismo motivo, porque es global

Por ejemplo aquí, vamos a probar la variable `numero` dentro de la función `llamar()` antes de que cambie de valor y después:

```js
var numero = 1;
llamar();

function cambiar() {
  numero = 2;
}

function llamar() {
  console.log("Antes del cambio: " + numero);
  cambiar();
  console.log("Después del cambio: " + numero);
}
```

Nótese que como la variable es **global**, si tu usas `numero` en la función `llamar`  sin invocar a `cambiar`, la variable tendrá el valor `1`, porque en efecto no ha habido cambio en ella.

Answer (score 0):

Basta con llamar la función cambiar en tu función llamar, de esa manera haces referencia al valor que tiene número en ese contexto, de lo contrario al ser global tu variable si no llamas la función su valor será 1.

```
var numero =1;
function cambiar(){
numero= 2
}

function llamar(){
cambiar();
}
```